# Capture after submit event (no ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a back end API method that returns a file (ASP.NET MVC) :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateReport(string param1, string param2)
{
    try
    {
        string fn = SomeMethodThatGenerateAnExcelFileAndReturnItsFullPath(param1, param2);
        return File(fn, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", Path.GetFileName(fn));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And I have a form in the front end :

```
<form id="genForm" action="@Url.Action("GenerateReport", "Report")" method="POST">
    <div class="card border-primary">
        <div class="card-header">Report parameters</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="dx-fieldset">
                <!-- inputs and params -->
                <div class="dx-field">
                    <div class="dx-field-label"></div>
                    <button class="dx-field-value" id="btn-generate"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And a javascript event that submits the form :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn-generate").click(function() {
        // some other modifications
        $("#genForm").submit();
    })
</script>
```

With this code when I click on the generate button it posts a request to the server (page is refreshing) and downloads a file (page stops refreshing when download is finished). While posting and downloading the browser is loading but the page's DOM does not change after.

My question is, since the DOM does not change, how to capture and handle the "after submit" event (actually when the download is finished).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The trick I've used in the past is to use a cookie to indicate whether the download has finished or not.

Here's how I did it in the past:

- Create an iframe to serve as the target of your submit; this is just so  you can capture the "load" event to check for the cookie.
- Capture the load event on that iframe to check for the cookie ... when the cookie is there, you know the download has finished.  (What's more, the value of the cookie can give you more information)
- submit the request
- after the file has downloaded, remove the iframe and run other code as needed.

I've always used an iframe, but this might work with a window.open() as well.

Comment: So I guess there's no practical solution for this ?